# Internal energy differential from the Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

The Gibbs free energy is defined as

$$ G = U-TS+pV$$

It is also known that the chemical potential is the per-particle Gibbs free energy so:

$$ G=\mu N $$

Now, putting the two together we get

$$ U = TS - pV + \mu N$$

I can also take the differential of the above:

$$ dU= d(TS) - d(pV) + d(\mu N) $$

Expanding the products and rearranging terms:

$$ dU = TdS-pdV + \mu dN + S dT - Vdp + N d\mu$$

This, however, seems at odds with the second law of thermodynamics which should write as

$$ dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN $$

My question is, how do I resolve this contradiction? From here I would conclude that

$$ SdT - Vdp + N d\mu =0 $$

Is this true? If so, how do I prove it? If not, where does the contradiction come from?

Comment: check out the [Gibbs-Duhem equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation). It is not a contradiction. Just like your last question, this stems from extensivity, and you can check this identity in specific examples.

Comment: thank you, that is the one! The term is indeed 0.

Comment: you may find these relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773545/meaning-of-thermodynamic-identity/773586#773586 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759539/do-chemical-potentials-stay-constant-in-chemical-equilibrium